# Why does page reload when uploading an image on tinymce editor?

Tags: php, tinymce, rich-text-editor

So in my tinymce text editor, I have added the plugins for image upload and the image handler function as well. But the problem is every time I upload or drag an image to the editor, the page reloads by itself and everything disappears. Here are the codes for TinyMce setup and image handlers

```
<script>
  const example_image_upload_handler = (blobInfo, progress) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');

  xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
    progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
  };

  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 403) {
      reject({ message: 'HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status, remove: true });
      return;
    }

    if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
      reject('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
      return;
    }

    const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
      reject('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
      return;
    }

    resolve(json.location);
  };

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    reject('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
  };

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

  xhr.send(formData);
});
  // change this value according to your HTML
  images_upload_handler: example_image_upload_handler
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#textarea',
    images_upload_handler: example_image_upload_handler,
    plugins: 'ai tinycomments mentions autolink  image link lists  searchreplace wordcount  footnotes editimage  powerpaste tinymcespellchecker autocorrect  inlinecss',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image footnotes | align | tinycomments | numlist bullist indent outdent',
    tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
    menubar: false,
    block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Subtitles=h2; Image Description=h5;',
    tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
    mergetags_list: [
      { value: 'First.Name', title: 'First Name' },
      { value: 'Email', title: 'Email' },
    ],
    ai_request: (request, respondWith) => respondWith.string(() => Promise.reject("See docs to implement AI Assistant")),
  });
</script>
```

this code exists in the same page as my form including the textarea.

and here is the code on`upload.php`.

```
<?php
  /***************************************************
   * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
   ***************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $imageFolder = "articleuploads/";

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
    if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    } else {
      header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
      return;
    }
  }

  // Don't attempt to process the upload on an OPTIONS request
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    return;
  }

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Determine the base URL
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
    $baseurl = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/") . "/";

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $baseurl . $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

As you can see, everything is done exactly the way it was explained in TinyMce documentation but I don't know if there is something wrong in this code or my other codes on the page.

I tried everything that was given in the documentation but it still reloads the page every time I upload an image.

One thing I am suspicious about is that in my form I also have a separate image button where a user uploads the image so I think maybe it is somehow related to that. But I am still not sure.